# Spring mvc annotation, can't find jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc" />  
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<bean name="viewResolver"class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">    
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>  
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
    </bean>
```

After adding  in this file, jetty throws error: *.jsp not found. If i remove annotation-driven here, everything works fine. Its very basic servelet.

Controller Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/deliveryETA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDeliveryETA(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("deliveryETA",new DeliveryETA());
    return "getDeliveryETA";
}
```

and getDeliveryETA.jsp :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="th" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="/v1/deliveryETA" commandName="deliveryETA">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Origin Address: <font color="red"><form:errors path="originAddress" /></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="originAddress" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Destination Address: <font color="red"><form:errors path="destinationAddress" /></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="destinationAddress" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `URL` are you trying to access? Could you post the `URI` mapped to the `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: I am trying to access uri for which i have created a controller, will add code  in the question for the controller.

Comment: Strange, I tried with same code and if I remove it says not found, if I add `mvc:annotation-driven` it works fine. My jsp is outside of WEB-INF though. Are you sure it doesn't work if you add that element?

Comment: Is your getDeliveryETA.jsp inside /WEB-INF/pages/ folder?

Comment: Yes. its location is : /webapp/WEB-INF/pages/getdeliveryETA.jsp

Comment: I have one controller which returns json strings that works fine. Just that jsp pages are not getting identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the View Resolver property values should be defined like this:

```
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
```

Comment: mentioned changes Didn't help.